# Why does 'of' use in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Why does second `of` -which is at immediate before comma- use in the sentence below?

What does it specify? (which subject, object or etc.)

> In Spain, as in the rest of world that I know **of**, the VAT tax (value
>   added) is included in the price.

This is one of the questions that makes me confused.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's a fixed expression: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/know-of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Know of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know-of-sb-sth)" is a phrasal verb consisting of a verb "know" and a preposition "of." It's normally followed by a noun phrase as a complement.

However, a preposition, when used with a relative clause, like this one, it can be *[stranded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding)* (used without a following complement).